# Multiple file uploader $_POST issue

Tags: php, arrays, post, file-upload

I have the following form that uses some jQuery to allow an array of files to be submitted:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="post" >
<input type="file" class="multi" name="test[]"  />
<input  type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

When I use `method="get"` I get the following URL when submitted:

```
http://website.com/index.php?test[]=image.jpg&test[]=image2.jpg&submit=submit
```

How do I gather the `test[]` array data using $_POST and/or $_FILE using `method="post"`?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a more flexible way to access the `$_FILES` if you dont know the input name

i did this one

```
$files = $_FILES;
foreach($files as $key =>$file)
{
 $uploaded["filename"] = $files[$key]["name"];
}

print_r($uploaded);
```

would print the filename

Answer (score 1):

This becomes an array on the server-end, and as such you can cycle through the values with a loop. Below is an example using the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($_FILES["test"] as $file) {
  // handle current file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to always submit file uploads with POST.

You then access the files on the server side via the `$_FILES` array.

[Tizag.com](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) has a good tutorial on file uploads.